# eigenvalue differential operator

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, differential-operators

I stuck to this problem for half day and have no idea how to start. Can anyone please help me.

Find all the eigenvalues of the following equation

$(\frac{d}{dx}+x)(y(x))=\lambda$$y(x)$

I tried to let $y(x)=e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$

Then I get the eigenvalue of $0$, have no idea how to find the rest of the eigenvalues.

I also tried to multiply both sides by $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$, then I get

$\frac{d}{dx}[(e^{\frac{x^2}{2}})(y(x)]=\lambda$$y(x)e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$

So is $0$ the ony eigenvalue?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. Try multiplying both sides by $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} $. You can rework the operator on the left and you will get something much nicer.

Comment: (Think product rule.)

Comment: I tried, so is 0 the only eigenvalue??

Comment: Not quite. Let $g(x) = e^{\frac{x^2}{1}} y(x) $. Then $g$ solves $g'(x) = \lambda g(x) $. What are the solutions to this?

Comment: So $g(x)=e^{\lambda x}$, then I put it back to the equation I get $y(x)=e^{\lambda x-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, so this is the eigenfunction?

Comment: Correct! What eigenvalues are admissible? These states are called coherent states by the way. Feel free to read into this if you are interested.

Comment: thx a lot you made my day!!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help. If this answer was satisfactory, please feel free to accept it so that the question doesn't keep getting put on the front page. :)